# SQL SELECT and UPDATE of first line of data prior to carriage return

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a field in a database named **Description** that is a Data Type of *text*. The first line of data is always taken from the "Client Name" field of another database, anything after the first carriage return contains internal notes taken on this client.

**Example**:

```
This is the first line.
NOTES: This is the second line that has notes.
```

I want to be able to query this field returning only the "This is the first line." part, as well as how to update this field.  Sometimes the Client Name gets changed and we want to update this field but maintain any notations that may exist.

Comment: You should do that in two fields and then concatenate in a select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple string operations like `LEFT/CHARINDEX` for `SELECT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(note VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO #tab VALUES('This is the first line.' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 
'NOTES: This is the second line that has notes.');

SELECT 
   CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), note) > 0
        THEN LEFT(note, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), note) - 1)
        ELSE note
   END AS first_line
FROM #tab;
```

And `REPLACE` for `UPDATE`:

```
DECLARE @new_value VARCHAR(100) = 'This is updated first line';

UPDATE #tab
SET note = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), note) > 0 
                THEN REPLACE(note, 
                   LEFT(note, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), note) - 1),
                   @new_value)
                ELSE @new_value
           END
-- WHERE ID = ?;

SELECT *
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/390221)**</kbd>

I've assumed that new line is `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)`.